# How to pass the asp.Identity object to a second register page

Tags: asp.net, identity

I am building a much more advanced registration process which consists of 3 pages, the first page is a form that grabs a username(email form) and a password with confirmation. The button click on this page creates the user in an unverified state in the db and redirects to the page where the profile is created. Once the create profile button is clicked and the profile is created in the db the redirect takes you to the Credit Card info page where the form is filled out, the credit card is verified and then that info is written to a table in the database.

I have disabled the loggedin user display in the header so that I can use the registrants First and Last name which arent entered until the Credit Card page. Since the identityUser is required for the sign on and thus to populate the loggedin user control, how can I pass this object from page to page?

**Code where original template was logging in the user**: (Note:I commented out the sign in code)

```
  Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userName As String = UserNameCtrl.Text
    Dim manager = New UserManager()
    Dim newuser = New IdentityUser() With {.UserName = userName}
    manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of IdentityUser)(manager) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False}
    Dim result = manager.Create(newuser, Password.Text)
    If result.Succeeded Then
        Session("email") = newuser.UserName
        Session("userid") = newuser.Id.ToString()
        'uncomment the code below if you want the auto sign in to occur
        'IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, newuser, isPersistent:=False)
        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Account/CreateProfile.aspx?Guid=" & newuser.Id.ToString()), Response)
    Else
        ErrorMessage.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode(result.Errors.FirstOrDefault())
    End If
End Sub
```

I now call this routine to sign in the user once the third page of the registration process is completed. (Session("userid") is the new registrants generated userid)

```
 Private Sub SignInUserOnFormCompletion()
    Dim manager = New UserManager()
    manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of IdentityUser)(manager) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False}
    Dim newuser = New IdentityUser() With {.Id = Session("userid").ToString()}
    IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, newuser, isPersistent:=False)
End Sub
```

The problem is the above doesnt work as the newuser somehow has different credentials. How can I pass the original newuser from the first page to the third page where I can use it in the SignInUserOnFormCompletion subroutine? Do I create a cookie and pass it around that way?
This is a new topic for me so I'm not familiar with the proper methods to accomplish this.

Comment: Why not do it on a single page and simplify things? Maybe by using the `Wizard` control, or else just having three `div` elements and make one visible at a time. Or maybe use a `MultiView` control?

Comment: In fact, what about [`CreateUserWizard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.aspx)?

Comment: the first comment is a potential workaround which ill have to utilize but the comments do not answer the question which is how to pass an object to another page

Comment: Session state doesn't work?

Comment: John, I reconfigured the three pages to use Multiview control and created a Private Shared variable for the page which is the identity object. It all works fine now. Post the Multiview as the answer with the global identity user variable and Ill check it as the answer.

Comment: Actually, your `Shared` variable doesn't work. If there are two users being created at once, the same value will be shared by both users. Use `Session` state instead.

Comment: So i can set an object to a session state variable? ie Session("identityuser") =MyIdentityUser  ?

Comment: Why not? It's exactly the same as saving an `int` in session state.

Comment: this line IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, newuser, isPersistent:=False) doesn't work anymore, IdentityHelper is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use multiple pages arranged as a wizard, then you will need to pass data between the pages.

However, if you use a single page with a `MultiView` or `Wizard` control, then you won't need to do that. Just arrange your current pages as separate views within the `MultiView`, and use `Session` state to retain data across the post backs.